# How to fix "compile error: End If without block If."

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

I got this code, and for whatever reason, the 'End If' can't find the block If statement. I've tried a couple solutions but I can't get it to work. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I'm unsure what else need to be said about the issue. So if there's anything else needed, please let me know.

The code is someone else's that I've edited. I'm still very new to VBA and still very much learning.

```
   If cStatus Is Nothing Then 'This is the block If statement that the End If should be tied to. 
       Set cStatus = Sheet1.Range("N1:N1000").Find(what:="Done, On-going")
         
         Do While Len(cStatus.Value) > 0
          Select Case LCase(cStatus.Value)
            Case "done": Set wsDest = Sheet4
            Case "on-going": Set wsDest = Sheet2
            Case Else: Set wsDest = Nothing
          End Select
        
          If Not wsDest Is Nothing Then
               cStatus.EntireRow.Cut _
               Destination:=wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
          End If 'Error does move to this one too. 
        
      End If 'The error is with this one here. 

  'Set cStatus = cStatus.Offset(1, 0) 'next source row
  Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: It is good to try indenting your code. You could see that the mentioned problematic code line is wrongly placed. It does not have `If`  before. I suppose that you should move it after `Loop`. And indent the `Loop` position to be inside `If ... End If` statement...

Comment: The `Do While ... Loop` and the `If ... End If` are incorrectly nested. One should be wholly inside the other or you will get a compiler error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I indent using "Rubberduck" https://test.rubberduckvba.com/Indenter I get this (note I added `Sub Test` to match the `End Sub`):

```vb
Sub Test()
    If cStatus Is Nothing Then 'This is the block If statement that the End If should be tied to.
        Set cStatus = Sheet1.Range("N1:N1000").Find(what:="Done, On-going")
        
        Do While Len(cStatus.Value) > 0
            Select Case LCase(cStatus.Value)
                Case "done": Set wsDest = Sheet4
                Case "on-going": Set wsDest = Sheet2
                Case Else: Set wsDest = Nothing
            End Select
            
            If Not wsDest Is Nothing Then
                cStatus.EntireRow.Cut _
                Destination:=wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            End If 'Error does move to this one too.
            
        End If 'The error is with this one here.
        
        'Set cStatus = cStatus.Offset(1, 0) 'next source row
    Loop
End Sub
```

See how `Do While` and `Loop` are not indented the same amount, and the second `End If` is not matching the indentation of the first `If`. Swap the two statements around and the indenting makes more sense

```vb
Sub Test()
    If cStatus Is Nothing Then 'This is the block If statement that the End If should be tied to.
        Set cStatus = Sheet1.Range("N1:N1000").Find(what:="Done, On-going")
        
        Do While Len(cStatus.Value) > 0
            Select Case LCase(cStatus.Value)
                Case "done": Set wsDest = Sheet4
                Case "on-going": Set wsDest = Sheet2
                Case Else: Set wsDest = Nothing
            End Select
            
            If Not wsDest Is Nothing Then
                cStatus.EntireRow.Cut _
                Destination:=wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            End If 'Error does move to this one too.
            
            'Set cStatus = cStatus.Offset(1, 0) 'next source row
        Loop
    End If 'The error is with this one here.
End Sub
```

---

Incidentally, you haven't explained your logic but I think maybe what you actually want is maybe this?:

```vb
Sub Test()
    If cStatus Is Nothing Then
        Set cStatus = Sheet1.Range("N1:N1000").Find(what:="Done, On-going")
    End If
    
    Do While Len(cStatus.Value) > 0
        Select Case LCase(cStatus.Value)
            Case "done": Set wsDest = Sheet4
            Case "on-going": Set wsDest = Sheet2
            Case Else: Set wsDest = Nothing
        End Select
        
        If Not wsDest Is Nothing Then
            cStatus.EntireRow.Cut _
            Destination:=wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If
        
        Set cStatus = cStatus.Offset(1, 0) 'next source row
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Better. The `Do While  ...  Loop` is wholly nested within the `If  ...  End If`